# Como pegar o input de um HTML com JS e depois passar pra um arquivo.JSON, em um aplicativo electron;

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, electron

[image: ele faz oq proposto na imagem]

Tenho um aplicativo **electron**. Existe um **input** no meu **html** que eu consigo **pegar** com um **JS**, quero **colocar** ele em um **arquivo json**. observe os seguintes códigos:

--- no html (index)

```
     <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 123 123 123" class="get-id" id="name"/>
      <button type="submit" id="send" class="get-button">get</button>
    </form>
```

--- no javascript (consume)

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   
    const name = document.querySelector("#name");
    value = name.value;
    console.log(value);
  
})
```

Ele funciona bem, igual está na imagem. O problema é que preciso por oque estiver dentro de "value" em um Json. Tentei usando a lib fs (file system), mas ela só funciona com node. Como faço isso? :d

Tentei exportar essa variável value e dar import no node, mas não sei se foi o escopo(?) já tentei criar uma api em node junto do express e consumir ela mas não consegui :d além de q deve ter um método mais eficiente.

O objetivo é cada vez que o get ser apertado esse arquivo seja atualizado com o valor dentro da textbox,
exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso terei a comunicação do código em python com a interface. To quebrando a cabeça nisso tem mais de 24h;

Answer (score 2):

Pra escrever em um arquivo você vai ter que usar o node mesmo

```
fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', 'content here');
```

Porém, pra usar o node você vai ter que usar no Electron o protocolo IPC

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main/

É um protocolo de mensageria de frontend para backend. Com isso você envia o json e escuta o evento no backend

Tem um exemplo aqui:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_inter_process_communication.htm

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(arg));
})
```

No frontend você manda assim:

```
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', { object: true })
```